# How to convert caffe layers to keras layers?

Tags: keras, caffe, keras-layer, keras-2, caffe2

I found the following layers in caffe prototxt file:

```
layer {
  name: "before_proj"
  type: "Silence"
  bottom: "xxxbefore_proj"
}

layer {
  name: "1_before_proj"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "conv4f"
  top: "xxx1_before_proj"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 200
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "concat_pred_rendered"
  type: "Concat"
  bottom: "conv4f"
  bottom: "conv_rendered_3"
  top: "conv4f_ext"
  concat_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
```

How to convert them into keras layers? Any hints welcomed. Thanks